# Application crashes when trying to set OnClick for button

Tags: button, android-studio, onclick

I'm new to Android Studio and am trying to set a OnClick listener for a button using XML. I used android:onClick but when I run the app and press the button it crashes.

Here is my XML:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Convert"
    android:id="@+id/convertButton"
    android:onClick="onConvertButtonClicked(View v)"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp"/>
```

Here is what my java code looks like:

```
public void onConvertButtonClicked(View v){...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in XML put the method name without the brackets or parameters {android:onClick="onConvertButtonClicked"}